# CORS for every origins

Tags: asp.net, cordova, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have developed an HTML5/Javascript mobile app that uses Apache Cordova to works on mobile. Backend is developed like WS RESTful (ASP.net MVC WebApi 2).

I have enabled CORS for testing my app but using a specified origin (like 'localhost:90') but I want to enable CORS for every origins (security is already handled with custom attributes on all web apis)... how can I open my apis to all over the world?

thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in your backend server.The wildcard `*` indicates all origins.
For ASP.net this link might help you out : https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api